# RAM and speed issue in importing two million entries of json objects

Tags: json, database, dataframe, dictionary, ram

I have a json file contain two million entries, where each entry contain the element of the form

```
{"id":"0704.0001","submitter":"Pavel Nadolsky","authors":"C. Bal\\'azs, E. L. Berger, P. M. Nadolsky, C.-P. Yuan","title":"Calculation of prompt diphoton production cross sections at Tevatron and\n  LHC energies","comments":"37 pages, 15 figures; published version","journal-ref":"Phys.Rev.D76:013009,2007","doi":"10.1103/PhysRevD.76.013009","report-no":"ANL-HEP-PR-07-12","categories":"hep-ph","license":null,"abstract":"  A fully differential calculation in perturbative quantum chromodynamics is\npresented for the production of massive photon pairs at hadron colliders. All\nnext-to-leading order perturbative contributions from quark-antiquark,\ngluon-(anti)quark, and gluon-gluon subprocesses are included, as well as\nall-orders resummation of initial-state gluon radiation valid at\nnext-to-next-to-leading logarithmic accuracy. The region of phase space is\nspecified in which the calculation is most reliable. Good agreement is\ndemonstrated with data from the Fermilab Tevatron, and predictions are made for\nmore detailed tests with CDF and DO data. Predictions are shown for\ndistributions of diphoton pairs produced at the energy of the Large Hadron\nCollider (LHC). Distributions of the diphoton pairs from the decay of a Higgs\nboson are contrasted with those produced from QCD processes at the LHC, showing\nthat enhanced sensitivity to the signal can be obtained with judicious\nselection of events.\n","versions":[{"version":"v1","created":"Mon, 2 Apr 2007 19:18:42 GMT"},{"version":"v2","created":"Tue, 24 Jul 2007 20:10:27 GMT"}],"update_date":"2008-11-26","authors_parsed":[["Bal\u00e1zs","C.",""],["Berger","E. L.",""],["Nadolsky","P. M.",""],["Yuan","C. -P.",""]]}
{"id":"0704.0002","submitter":"Louis Theran","authors":"Ileana Streinu and Louis Theran","title":"Sparsity-certifying Graph Decompositions","comments":"To appear in Graphs and Combinatorics","journal-ref":null,"doi":null,"report-no":null,"categories":"math.CO cs.CG","license":"http://arxiv.org/licenses/nonexclusive-distrib/1.0/","abstract":"  We describe a new algorithm, the $(k,\\ell)$-pebble game with colors, and use\nit obtain a characterization of the family of $(k,\\ell)$-sparse graphs and\nalgorithmic solutions to a family of problems concerning tree decompositions of\ngraphs. Special instances of sparse graphs appear in rigidity theory and have\nreceived increased attention in recent years. In particular, our colored\npebbles generalize and strengthen the previous results of Lee and Streinu and\ngive a new proof of the Tutte-Nash-Williams characterization of arboricity. We\nalso present a new decomposition that certifies sparsity based on the\n$(k,\\ell)$-pebble game with colors. Our work also exposes connections between\npebble game algorithms and previous sparse graph algorithms by Gabow, Gabow and\nWestermann and Hendrickson.\n","versions":[{"version":"v1","created":"Sat, 31 Mar 2007 02:26:18 GMT"},{"version":"v2","created":"Sat, 13 Dec 2008 17:26:00 GMT"}],"update_date":"2008-12-13","authors_parsed":[["Streinu","Ileana",""],["Theran","Louis",""]]}
{"id":"0704.0003","submitter":"Hongjun Pan","authors":"Hongjun Pan","title":"The evolution of the Earth-Moon system based on the dark matter field\n  fluid model","comments":"23 pages, 3 figures","journal-ref":null,"doi":null,"report-no":null,"categories":"physics.gen-ph","license":null,"abstract":"  The evolution of Earth-Moon system is described by the dark matter field\nfluid model proposed in the Meeting of Division of Particle and Field 2004,\nAmerican Physical Society. The current behavior of the Earth-Moon system agrees\nwith this model very well and the general pattern of the evolution of the\nMoon-Earth system described by this model agrees with geological and fossil\nevidence. The closest distance of the Moon to Earth was about 259000 km at 4.5\nbillion years ago, which is far beyond the Roche's limit. The result suggests\nthat the tidal friction may not be the primary cause for the evolution of the\nEarth-Moon system. The average dark matter field fluid constant derived from\nEarth-Moon system data is 4.39 x 10^(-22) s^(-1)m^(-1). This model predicts\nthat the Mars's rotation is also slowing with the angular acceleration rate\nabout -4.38 x 10^(-22) rad s^(-2).\n","versions":[{"version":"v1","created":"Sun, 1 Apr 2007 20:46:54 GMT"},{"version":"v2","created":"Sat, 8 Dec 2007 23:47:24 GMT"},{"version":"v3","created":"Sun, 13 Jan 2008 00:36:28 GMT"}],"update_date":"2008-01-13","authors_parsed":[["Pan","Hongjun",""]]}
```

I was able to import the json object line by line with `json.loads` into a list,

```
with open(json_file, "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        output_data.append(json.loads(line))
```

where each item in the list was a dictionary

```
output_data[-1]
{'id': 'supr-con/9609004',
 'submitter': 'Masanori Ichioka',
 'authors': 'Naoki Enomoto, Masanori Ichioka and Kazushige Machida (Okayama Univ.)',
 'title': 'Ginzburg Landau theory for d-wave pairing and fourfold symmetric vortex\n  core structure',
 'comments': '12 pages including 8 eps figs, LaTeX with jpsj.sty & epsfig',
 'journal-ref': 'J. Phys. Soc. Jpn. 66, 204 (1997).',
 'doi': '10.1143/JPSJ.66.204',
 'report-no': None,
 'categories': 'supr-con cond-mat.supr-con',
 'license': None,
 'abstract': "  The Ginzburg Landau theory for d_{x^2-y^2}-wave superconductors is\nconstructed, by starting from the Gor'kov equation with including correction\nterms up to the next order of ln(T_c/T). Some of the non-local correction terms\nare found to break the cylindrical symmetry and lead to the fourfold symmetric\ncore structure, reflecting the internal degree of freedom in the pair\npotential. Using this extended Ginzburg Landau theory, we investigate the\nfourfold symmetric structure of the pair potential, current and magnetic field\naround an isolated single vortex, and clarify concretely how the vortex core\nstructure deviates from the cylindrical symmetry in the d_{x^2-y^2}-wave\nsuperconductors.\n",
 'versions': [{'version': 'v1', 'created': 'Wed, 25 Sep 1996 14:17:09 GMT'}],
 'update_date': '2009-10-30',
 'authors_parsed': [['Enomoto', 'Naoki', '', 'Okayama Univ.'],
  ['Ichioka', 'Masanori', '', 'Okayama Univ.'],
  ['Machida', 'Kazushige', '', 'Okayama Univ.']]}
```

But I encountered several issues. First this is not ideal like a panda dataframe where I can search for the id and the related entry. Second, the original json file was around 3.5GB, but when I imported the json file into the computer, the RAM increased by around 10 GB. It's getting hard to operate it around.

Though it seemed to be working, I felt there's something wrong with the approach, mainly regarding the operations efficiency and the suitable data type, since the next step is to perform repeated search of this database file.

Is there some way to get around this? i.e. directly import the json file into a panda dataframe, or some types of suitable dictionary object? Also, why was the RAM increased by 10 GB, is there a way to deal with it?